# How to transfer a part of a device array to another device array using PGI cuda fortran compiler?

Tags: cuda, fortran, pgi

Now I want to transfer a piece of a device array to another device array using following code:

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer :: a(5,5,5,5)
  integer, device :: a_d(5,5,5,5),b_d(5,5,5,5)
  a=0
  a_d=a
  b_d(1:2,:,:,:)=a_d(2:3,:,:,:)
end program
```

The pgi compiler returns following error for `b_d(1:2,:,:,:)=a_d(2:3,:,:,:)`:

> PGF90-S-0519-More than one device-resident object in assignment.

How to solve this problem or, is there an efficient way to transfer only a piece of a device array to another device array?

Comment: I ahve zero experience with Fortran, but, can you create an intermediate `integer` that is not in device and copy to there and from there?

Comment: I am pretty sure that answer will be that a slicing copy assignment between two device variables requires running a kernel on the device, unlike a simple assignment which generates a cudaMemcpy call. There might be some sort of fancy cuf loop based solution you could try, or maybe a cudaMemcpy2D call instead. Maybe someone from PGI can chime in....

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says the following:

> **3.4.2. Implicit Data Transfer in Expressions**
>
> Some limited data transfer can be enclosed within expressions. In
>   general, the rule of thumb is all arithmetic or operations must occur
>   on the host, which normally only allows one device array to appear on
>   the right-hand-side of an expression.

I'm pretty sure that means that a slicing assignment of the kind you are trying to do is not supported because you have a device array on the left hand side of the expression.

I am not sure what is the best way to solve this. `cudaMemcpy2D` will definitely work if you can deduce the pitch of the arrays. Hopefully someone from PGI can edit a solution into this community wiki entry.